# PHP preg-match only 1 row

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have a table. How to put only table ip:port?

```
<table>
<tr><th colspan="3">Total Socks In List : 78</th><th style="border:none;background:none"></th></tr>
<tr><th>IP Address : Port</th><th>Country</th><th>Last Updated</th></tr>
<tr><td>166.78.xxx.xx:36xx</td><td><img src="../images/flag/UNITED STATES.png" width="18" height="12" alt="UNITED STATES.png"/>
UNITED STATES</td><td>18/06/2014 02:06:58</td></tr>
<tr><td>68.40.xxx.xxx:23xx</td><td><img src="../images/flag/UNITED STATES.png" width="18" height="12" alt="UNITED STATES.png"/>UNITED STATES</td><td>18/06/2011 02:06:07</td></tr>
<tr><td>76.184.xxx.xxx:72xx</td><td><img src="../images/flag/UNITED STATES.png" width="18" height="12" alt="UNITED STATES.png"/>UNITED STATES</td><td>18/06/2011 02:06:13</td></tr>
</table>
```

Here is my code php:

```
<?php 
function njipuk($awal,$keri,$­tulisane)
{ 
    $kata = explode($awal,$tulis­ane); 
    $kata = explode($keri,$kata[­1]); 
    return $kata[0]; 
} 
$page = file_get_contents("mysite/"); 
echo njipuk('</td></tr><tr><td>','</td>',$page); 
?>
```

Comment: this my code php

<?php
function njipuk($awal,$keri,$­tulisane){
$kata = explode($awal,$tulis­ane);
$kata = explode($keri,$kata[­1]);
return $kata[0];
}
$page = file_get_contents("http://mysite/")

echo njipuk('</td></tr><tr><td>','</td>',$page);
?>

Comment: When I edited your question I added a semi-colon after your `file_get_contents(...)` - if that wasn't just a typo transferring it to the comment, you'll need to add that. In the future, add your code directly to your question by editing your question.

Comment: So is your `<table>...</table>` what you are reading in from "mysite/"? Or are you reading in some other data and generating that table?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a DOM Parser. Processing HTML with regex, while possible in limited cases, is not usually practical nor recommended. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags for some entertaining answers related to this.

Comment: this reading from this site http://www.socks5proxies.com/index.php?action=freesocks&country=UNITED+STATES,